# pod didn't trigger scale-up: 1 In sufficient cpu, 1 Insufficient memory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running GKE Standard, and I am getting  `pod didn't trigger scale-up: 1 In sufficient cpu, 1 Insufficient memory`  error when my cluster spawns a new Job. Essentially, I have a very small pod running 24/7 to handle incoming requests on a fairly small node, but my individual pods all need to be very powerful. However, I am coming to learn that the node needs to be at least as big as the biggest pod. Does this mean I am doomed to have to spend significant money 24/7 simply because my pods need to be large (e2-standard-32 at least). I set up autoscaling with minimum 0 and maximum 10 nodes.

Do I need GKE Autopilot for this which charges per CPU and memory consumption rather than per node?

Edit: I got rid of this error by following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool):  Basically, I need to increase the node size. But my question remains. Do I have to pay for this node 24/7 even though I am rarely using it?

Here is my Job spec:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  generateName: opensfm-job-
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: opensfm
          image: gcr.io/fliermapper/opensfm-image:fliermappertag1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: (our arguments)
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "3000Mi"
              cpu: "2000m"
            limits:
              memory: "4000Mi"
              cpu: "16000m"
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Comment: You have a pretty big delta between cpu request and cpu limit.  Do you expect jobs to actually need 16 CPUs?

Comment: yes, in our case, we are running image processing structure from motion, so we actually likely need 32 cpus or even 60

Comment: Autopilot using Spot pods seems like a good option for you, but you'll only be able to use up to ~48 CPUs per pod.  If you really might need 48+ CPUs per pod, then for now I'd suggest using Std with Node auto-provisioning ( https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning ) and I'd suggest using Spot instance types if you can tolerate pre-emption.

Answer (score 0):

In GKE for Standard mode a management fee of $0.10 per cluster per hour is applied, irrespective of cluster size or topology.In Standard mode, GKE uses Compute Engine instances worker nodes in the cluster. You are billed for each of those instances according to [Compute Engine's pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing), until the nodes are deleted. Compute Engine resources are billed on a per-second basis with a one-minute minimum usage cost.You can use the [Google Cloud pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to estimate your monthly GKE charges, including cluster management fees and worker node pricing.

For more information on pricing details of GKE refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing).

Comment: @WalterMorawa As you already mentioned that the error got resolved in the question `But my question remains. Do I have to pay for this node 24/7 even though I am rarely using it?` and wanted the information on payment details added the information regarding pricing details of GKE.

Comment: Did you mean to mention autopilot instead of standard above?

Comment: @WalterMorawa From the question I understood that you are using standard and wanted to know if you need to pay completely 24/7 even if you are rarely using the machine so gave information on pricing details for the standard type. correct me if my understanding is wrong.